# Drupal Template Variables

Tags: php, drupal

Something that has been bothering me since I started using drupal is how exactly does the php engine know which $node/$classes/$attributes you are referring to in template files. these variables are never declared as globals, so how does the php engine figure out what "$node" you are referring to??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://drupal.org/node/223430 which states

> The main role of the preprocessor is to set up variables to be placed
>   within the template (`.tpl.php`) files. From Drupal 7 they apply to
>   templates and functions, whereas in Drupal 6 preprocess functions only
>   apply to theming hooks implemented as templates. Plain theme functions
>   do not interact with preprocessors.

Look at the `template_preprocess*` and the `template_process` referred to in the [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7).  These functions show you the code that set up the various variables that you can access in your node template.

In a similar manner, you can also add your own preprocess code in a theme function to add to the variables available in your tpl.php file like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   $variables['hello'] = 'Look at me now!';
}
```

After this, you can reference `$hello` in your `node.tpl.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

These variables are set by Drupal's templating engine.